# XML gets deformed after sending it via email in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, xml, linq, email, sharepoint

I am building an XML using linq to xml. Then I am converting it to string to sent it via email. The xml is the email body. The xml looks ok prior to being sent, and also the string which gets the converted xdocument looks alright. but after sending the email, the xml looks deformed.

Here is how I create the XML document:

```
private static XDocument CreateXmlDocument()
    {
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
            new XElement("Node1",
                new XElement("Node2",
                    new XElement("Node3", "TEST"),
                    new XElement("Node4", "TEST"),
                    new XElement("Node5", "TEST"),
                    new XElement("Node6", "TEST")),
            new XElement("Node7",
                new XElement("Node8",
                    new XElement("Node9", "TEST"),
                    new XElement("Node10", "TEST")),
                new XElement("Node11",
                    new XElement("Node12", "TEST"),
                    new XElement("Node13", string.Empty))),
            new XElement("Node14",
                new XElement("Node15", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node16", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node17", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node18", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node19", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node20", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node21", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node22", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node23", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node24", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node25", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node26", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node27",
                    new XElement("Node28",
                        new XElement("Node29", "TEST1"),
                        new XElement("Node30", "TEST2"))),
                new XElement("Node31", "TEST"),
                new XElement("Node32", "TEST"))));

        return xDoc;
    }
```

Here is how I send the email:

```
private static bool SendEmail(string subject, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("spSiteAddress"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    bool isEmailServerSet = SPUtility.IsEmailServerSet(web);

                    if (isEmailServerSet)
                    {
                        bool appendHtmlTag = false;
                        bool htmlEncode = true;
                        bool mailSuccessfullySend = false;

                        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                        {
                            mailSuccessfullySend = SPUtility.SendEmail(web, appendHtmlTag, htmlEncode, _email, subject, message);
                        });

                        return mailSuccessfullySend;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

And here is the email I receive:

[image]

Any ideas anyone?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out what the problem was.
The contents of the email was interpreted as being html and that led to strange characters appearing.
The solution was, I set the content type of the email to text/plain.
The way I included this option when sending the email was that I used a StringDictionary as a parameter.

Here you can find information on the 4 possible overloads of the SendEmail function:

[MSDN - SPUtility.SendEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.SendEmail.aspx)

Also, here is a link showing how to use the StringDictionary when sending an email:

[Sending email using SPUtility.SendEmail using StringDictionary](http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2008/05/using-the-undocumented-sputilitysendemail-method/)

So, to sum it up, the fix was **specifying the type of the email content to text/plain**.

Hope that helps.